# C exit codes and atexit() in a realtime / non-batch app

Tags: c, error-handling, exit, exit-code, atexit

I'm writing a game in which a number of different conditions can cause a failure, for example an image or shader failed to load, OpenGL failed to get a valid context, etc.

In an ideal world, I'd like to use exit codes in the way I believe was intended for C, i.e. non-zero for failure conditions. However, there are some factors that play into this:

- In using non-zero exit codes, `atexit()` is not called, unfortunately for me as my program cleanup is handled hierarchically via a single `atexit()` registration  in `main()`, which I like.
- It occurs to me that given the nature of the application - a game has an indefinite running time unlike a batch program  - there may never be a practical situation in which the exit codes are *actually used*. It's not like e.g. a command line image converter called by a Makefile which needs to know whether the program succeeded or failed via its exit code, thus determining whether or not to continue with the build. The likelihood is that if anything is wrong with the program at runtime, such as missing files, that's a problem I fix myself, then proceed smoothly.

**What arguments can be made for and against using non-zero exit codes in my situation?**

Comment: `atexit()` functions are called in normal termination, this is not related to error codes. If `exit()` is called or `main()` returns then functions registered in `atexit()` should get called.

Comment: @Veltas Yes. That's what I stated in my question. Why are you repeating what I already know?

Comment: I said the opposite. Functions registered with `atexit()` are called with non-zero return codes. You wrote "in using non-zero exit codes, `atexit()` is not called".

Comment: @Veltas So are you saying that "normal termination" includes situations where the exit code is non-zero?

Comment: Personally, I use exit codes intensively. Please remember, atexit handlers are called from the thread that calls exit. If you want per-thread handlers, you can use a pthread_key_create destructor

Comment: Yes, normal termination includes situations where the exit code is non-zero. Try it yourself in a small example.

Comment: @Veltas I believe you; I think that I always confused the terms "normal program termination" and "successful program termination". If you place an answer, I can accept - thanks.

Comment: I'd like to point out, that in the case of program termination it's a moot point (and actually discouraged) to clear up everything. All what this does is, that it forces the OS to swap in resources it may have moved out of system memory – only for that very memory to be discarded a few moments later. Just terminate the process; this implicitly frees all memory and closes all handles; the only reason for a clean teardown is if running in Valgrind or similar to check that there are no memory leaks. In the `atexit` handler you should place only things that the OS can not clean up for you.

Comment: @datenwolf: Although a legitimate use (other than to make debugging clearer) would be to perform a required effect external to the program's memory, e.g. writing an exit status to a file, or ending a calculation in some output. Closing files is done automatically, of course.

Comment: @Veltas: I was referring to iterating over each and every class instance, delete-ing / free-ing it, closeing every open OS handle and such stuff. This is just madness. Of course, things that absolutely must be done before program termination are fair game (like finishing some file output or resetting the modem).

Comment: @datenwolf, I must disagree (with due respect as a user of linmath and ongoing follower of yours on SO) about yours being the better way. If a program is well-structured into components that have dynamic lifespans that are not directly mapped to the lifetime of the program, and where memory consumption is relatively high per such component, I think it is preferable to ensure that every component has the ability to clean up after itself ASAP. This ensures program flexibility in the long run and is the one way to stay safe if you later realise you need to juggle memory at runtime.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: Being able to clean up behind yourself over a prolonged runtime is a completely different thing, that doing all that cleanup in the case of a requested program termination. Best case scenario all the cleanup code executed and memory allocations being torn down are readily available. Worst case scenario *all* of it has been swapped out by the OS (and even if you don't have swap space for allocations configured, program text will eventually get swapped out, unless you lock it to memory, which most OSs don't allow for regular users).

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: And if you want a second opinion on that, look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx

Comment: @datenwolf I'm laughing, because it's moot: If this is even an issue for you, it means your program isn't structured the way I describe above (as mine typically are), and thus probably needs better structure (see Peter's comment in that post). It should be part of your standard development process to have structured your program to free what it allocates; I make one call in atexit() that hierarchically frees all that is  allocated, subcomponent by subcomponent (program structure = tree). Best of all, unlike "free indiscriminately", it covers indefinite lifetimes as well as exit on fatal error.

Comment: @datenwolf: I hoped that it was clear from my comment that I agree with you. You're right, freeing everything without debugging reasons is unnecessary.

Comment: On the subject of "unnecessary free'ing" that has dominated the clutter of these comments, I would suggest `assert(atexit(/* ... */));` and then getting on with your lives.

Comment: @Veltas As noted in my last comment, it was unneeded advice ;) Next time, best we all stick to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Triggering registered `atexit()` functions

Contrary to your question, functions registered with `atexit()` are still called even when the program attempts to return a non-zero termination status to the host environment. A call to `exit()`, or the `main()` function returning, will trigger the functions registered with `atexit()`, regardless of the value given.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_stuff(void)
{
    puts("Stuff");
}

int main(void)
{
    atexit(print_stuff);
    exit(1);
}
```

This will print `Stuff`, even though `1` is returned.

### Technical details

By the ISO C standard, the functions registered in `atexit()` are called after `exit()` is called. The following situations are also defined as calling `exit()` (and therefore triggering the functions registered with `atexit()`):

1. `main()` returning is equivalent to calling `exit()`.
2. After the final thread calls `thrd_exit()`, `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` is called.

The following are possible implementation-defined sources of calling `exit()`:

1. The default signal handler for `SIGTERM`.
2. The default constraint handler before using `set_constraint_handler_s()`.

The standard mentions the following situations where `exit()` and the calls to functions registered with `atexit()` are circumvented:

1. An unhandled `SIGABRT` or a `SIGABRT` that finishes being handled by a function registered with `signal()`. `SIGABRT` can be raised by `abort()`.
2. Calling `_Exit()`.
3. Calling `quick_exit()`.

The host environment for your implementation may terminate the program in some situations without calling functions registered with `atexit()`, such as after a [segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segfault).

## Regarding exit codes for a game

Your choice of exit code shouldn't matter too much for a game. Yes, you won't be relying on a shell script to run your game and report errors to the user. Error feedback is probably more useful in the form of dialog popups, a log, or stderr for systems like Linux.

Comment: Nice.  You already had my up-vote; I'm not able to give another.  We should probably clean all these comments.